# How to send an array to a store to initialize in store with Vuex?

Tags: store, vuex, mutators

I am building a front-end application and I started to use vuex framework with vue front-end library. I have a state and I want to fill it by initial values, sending values with an array. My question is, How can I initialize state ? Do I need to follow action-mutation path for that ? Or just directly manipulate state as a start up only

Answer (score 0):

A typical store is like this:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        foo: [],
        bar: 1
    }
});
```

Just initialize the values there inside the `state` property.

However, if you want to initialize your state repeatedly, you can do it with a mutation:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        foo: [],
        bar: 1
    },
    mutations: {
        initialization(state) {
            state.foo = [];
            state.bar = 1;
         }
    }
});
```